# react-router-redux re-trigger a LOCATION_CHANGE to back after few seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-redux

After a few hours searching in google and digging into my code, i just realize that i need help. Can't explain myself what is happening here but i will try to be the most clear possible.

### The algorithm:

I made a button component that trigger a `POST` request to the server, when the promise is fulfilled the router push the new route, clean the old state of the current component (`onLeave` hook) and mount the new component at the new route. When the component is mounted (`componentDidMount`) it trigger a `GET` request with to get the previous saved data.

### The problem:

It works perfectly, the new route is pushed, the state is setted and the component mounted **without any error log or state inconsistency**... 5 seconds (more or less) later, the router re-trigger by itself a `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` and get back to the previous route.

I have no idea why this happens. I first thought that for any reason i was manipulating the state of the next component in the previous route or something, but no.

Another possibility is in the `CLEAN_ON_LEAVE` action triggered on the route leave hook but it have no sense for me, I'm just triggering the reducer of a completely isolated component.

Google didn't give me much information about the problem, so here i am.

### The code:

#### The action that make a POST request and push the route:

```
export const savePlan = (date, plan) => {
  const postData = { plan_date: date, planification: plan };
  return dispatch => {
    post(`${API_URL}/save_plan`, postData)
      .then(res => {
        browserHistory.push(`/social-planning/plan/${res.data.id}`);
      })
      .catch(res => {
        console.log('error');
        console.log({res});
      });
  }
}
```

#### Action that makes the GET request in the new component mounting lifecycle:

```
export const getPlan = (id) => {
  return dispatch => {
    get(`${API_URL}/plans/${id}`)
      .then(res => {
        const { plan_date, planification } = res.data;
        dispatch(doDispatch(creators.set_planning_view_date, plan_date));
        dispatch(doDispatch(creators.set_planning_view_planification, planification));
      })
      .catch(res => {
        console.log({res});
      })
  }
}
```

#### Reducer for that component/action:

```
const planningView = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case creators.set_planning_view_date:
      return { ...state, plan_date: action.payload };

    case creators.set_planning_view_planification:
      return { ...state, planification: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

#### componentDidMount trigger:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { planId } = this.props.params;
    const { getPlan } = this.props;
    getPlan(planId);
  }
```

#### Routes config:

```
<Route path='social-planning/planner' component={Planner} onEnter={isLoggedIn} onLeave={leaveCleaner} />
<Route path='social-planning/plan/:planId' component={PlanningView} onEnter={isLoggedIn} />
```

#### leaveCleaner:

```
export const leaveCleaner = () => {
  STORE.dispatch({ type: 'CLEAN_ON_LEAVE' });
}
```

#### Reducer that catch the leave action creator:

```
case CLEAN_ON_LEAVE:
      return {
        ...initialState,
        cells: [...setCells()],
        compare_posts: [],
        post_prev_data: []
      }
```

So, there is the relevant code (but if you need more i can show it)... anyway, here are some extra data (images):

*The state progression with redux dev tools and the correct new route mount, then the re-triggering of location_change:*
[image: The state progression with redux dev tools]

*Second location change diff state*
[image: second location change diff state]

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: you have a plain `/social-planning` route? if so, does that have `exact` because it may be what highjacks it.

Comment: Yes, i have a plain `/social-planning` route: `<Route path='social-planning' component={SocialPlanning} onEnter={isLoggedIn} />`, the routes dependents of it need to be nested routes?

Comment: depends. if it's nested, the other route needs to be within the component `{SocialPlanning}` and not on same level or you need `exact` - worth a shot.

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance but: what is `exact` exactly?

Comment: well. an exact match, not partial. say  `path='social-planning' ` one will also catch `path='social-planning/planner/foo' `. so exactly `social-planning` with no arguments, go to that component, else, go to more specific. this is why nested routes allow you to define stuff in the component that first hits. it composes nice but it can be counter intuitive at first

Comment: `const Foo = () => <div>common stuff for both like headers or auth check <Route path='foo/bar' component={Bar}/></div>;
...
<Route path='foo' component={Foo} />`

Comment: didn't works, im trying a completely different route like: `path='planning/:planId'` and happens the same. But if i navigate directly from the browser searchbar, the problem disappears.

I'm gonna dig more into nested components.

Comment: sorry man, never used the redux router, just the plain one. good luck

Comment: @DimitarChristoff no worries, thanks for the advices.